# Transposing Column and removing duplicates

Tags: excel, vba

I successfully transposed my desired column from vertical to horizontal on "sheet2" of my workbook. My next goal is to remove duplicate dates and sort them ascending.

```
Sub CopyTransposed(rngSource As Range, rngTargetCell As Range)
rngTargetCell.Resize(rngSource.Columns.Count, rngSource.Rows.Count).Value = _
    Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(rngSource)
End Sub

Sub test()

CopyTransposed Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2:F100"), 
Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1").RemoveDuplicates


End Sub
```

I must have the .removeduplicates in the wrong place. Also, where would the ascending dates go in the code?? Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The official documentation of the [Range.RemoveDuplicates method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.removeduplicates) has an example how to use it correctly.

But the issue here is that the method can only remove duplicate **rows** but you try to remove the duplicate columns. So you can use it on a range of mutliple rows like `F2:F100` but you cannot use it on a range of multiple columns `B1:CW1`.

So you need to remove the duplicates **before you transpose** in your `rngSource`. Note that will change your source data.

```
Sub test()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2:F100").RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo
    CopyTransposed Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2:F100"), Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1")
End Sub
```

If you don't want to change your source data then you would need to copy the source into a (temporary) sheet without transposing, remove the dupicates there, and then transpose.

```
Sub test()
    'create temporary sheet
    Dim wsTemp As Worksheet
    Set wsTemp = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(After:=ThisWorkbook.Sheets(ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Count))

    On Error GoTo REMOVE_TEMPSHEET 'make sure temp sheet gets removed if something goes wrong

    Dim SourceRange As Range
    Set SourceRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("F2:F100")

    Dim TmpRange As Range
    Set TmpRange = wsTemp.Range("A1").Resize(SourceRange.Rows.Count, SourceRange.Columns.Count)

    'copy to temporary range
    TmpRange.Value = SourceRange.Value

    'remove duplicates
    TmpRange.RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlNo

    'transpose
    CopyTransposed TmpRange, Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B1")

    'remove temporary sheet
REMOVE_TEMPSHEET:
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    wsTemp.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Raise Err.Number, Err.Source, Err.Description, Err.HelpFile, Err.HelpContext
    End If
End Sub
```

You might want to use `Application.ScreenUpdating = True/False` to prevent flickering.

Comment: Thank you so much @peh . How would i go about sorting these dates ascending??

Comment: Sort after removing the duplicates but before transposing using the [Range.Sort method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.sort) on `TmpRange`